# payara deployment issue: Jersey loggingFilter not found

Tags: jakarta-ee, jersey, payara

When trying to deploy my maven EAR file to payara server (5.181), I receive the following error message:

```
[2018-07-09T10:58:00.971+0200] [Payara 5.181] [SCHWERWIEGEND] [] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=46 _ThreadName=admin-thread-pool::admin-listener(1)] [timeMillis: 1531126680971] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter]]
```

The maven build works fine so I suppose it must be a payara specific issue when publishing the application (?).

Comment: What version of Jersey does that version of Payara use? LoggingFilter was removed in Jersey 2.26. You need to use LoggingFeature now. https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/logging_chapter.html

Answer (score 1):

Payara Server 5.181 uses [Jersey 2.26](https://github.com/payara/Payara/blob/payara-server-5.181/nucleus/pom.xml#L231), which doesn't contain the `LoggingFilter` class anymore. You should check your pom.xml whether it refers to an older version of Jersey. If you want your build to be in line with Payara Server 5.181, you should use the [payara-embedded-all:5.181](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Cfish.payara.extras%7Cpayara-embedded-all%7C5.181%7Cjar) dependency with provided scope instead of depending on a specific version of Jersey.

And, as  Paul suggests in the comment, you need to use `LoggingFeature` instead: https://jersey.github.io/documentation/2.26/logging_chapter.html